# How to prevent creating new data in MySQL from a duplicate HTTP request

Tags: nestjs

How do I prevent a new user from creating if the last user HTTP request created was less than 30 seconds of the current time?

My code works if I send the requests one by one but it will start creating two users when I send simultaneous requests using Postman runner. I already tested with MySQL lock mode and isolation level.

```
 async createUser() {
    const start = dayjs(
      dayjs().subtract(30, 'seconds').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    );
    const end = dayjs(
      dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    );
    const exisingUser = await this.userRepository.find({
      where: {
        created_at: Between(
          start.format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.000000'),
          end.format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.000000'),
        ),
      },
    });
    console.log(`existing user count ${exisingUser.length} `);

    if (exisingUser.length > 0) {
      throw new HttpException(
        'Last user  is created less than 30 seconds',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }

    return this.userRepository.save({
      name: 'test',
      email: 'test@mail.com',
    });
  }
```

[Repo link to reproduce the problem.](https://github.com/ap30422/mysql-test.git)

Comment: This is not up to the databae, this is up to the application to detect.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of database locks. Database locks arethere to control concurrent access to the same resource and should be in place for as short period of time as possible.

Comment: Inserts from two independent http requests do not require concurrent access to the same resource - unless you use myisam storage engine that can only lock at table level, not at row level.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Put everything needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please don't ask new questions in comments. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: If you want to prevent multiple simulanious requests to create database entries, then you cannot directly access the database from the http request handler code, unless you are prepared to keep the database connection and locks open for 30 secs, rendering your app unresponsive. Implement a queuing system in your app and the user creations can be handled by the queue. The queue will be aware of all user creation requeats and can reject the ones made too close to each other.

Comment: I mean I'm NOT talking about the database lock. I'm thinking about creating a Redis cache key when the app start processing a request and remove that key after the request is completed.

Comment: In this case I would delete this question and ask a new one with this detail and properly tagged with redis.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently checking if any users were created within a specific timeframe using a query. However, when dealing with simultaneous requests, this method might not be reliable due to potential race conditions.

To address this more effectively, consider utilizing database transactions and locking. This ensures that the process of checking for existing users and creating a new user happens as a single, indivisible operation, eliminating concerns about race conditions.

By employing TypeORM transactions, you guarantee that the examination for existing users and the creation of a new user occur as a unified and secure operation. This helps to prevent challenges associated with simultaneous requests.
More here => https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions

Comment: 1) transactions have nothing to do with race conditions. The purpose of transactions is consistency - a set of modifications are either completely made or not made at all. Your confusion comes from the fact that transactions may influence the lifespan of certain locks. 2) Two concurrent inserts will not normally be prevented by locks. You could use table locks, but then the database connection must be kept open for 30 seconds designated by the OP, which would render the webapp unresponsive.